# How to Log or Capture Print Driver Specific Preferences?

Tags: c#, printing, drivers, printers, epson

I'm trying to capture or log all the print settings for any given print job that I make on Windows (in particular from Photoshop, but I don't think that matters much).

In particular, I want to log or capture the Printer Driver specific settings. I have an Epson 3880 which has many many print settings (colour/quality/media type). My understanding is that these settings are provided via the Specific Printer Drivers and not Windows?

Reason I want to do this is because I'm sampling many new paper types for fine art, and want to tweak and record all the settings I use for tracking. I found a few software monitors, but all they seem to track from the print jobs are No of copies, and paper orientation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this programmatically? The spooler API; setup FindNextPrinterChangeNotification, get a jobid then GetJob() for a JOB_INFO_2 & examine the DEVMODE struct which *may* contain custom OEM data stuck on the end

Comment: Thanks Alex - I was asking to do it anyway possible. A lot of the answers/code I've read goes down the API route, or the WMI route or calling various DLLs, which is fine but they don't expand on the information available. I'll have to see if this will get some info on what I need.